# How can I move NEAR token from one account to other using contract?

Tags: nearprotocol

Disclaimer: this is a community question from a chat published here for better discoverability.

> I want to transfer NEAR token from `a.testnet` to `b.testnet`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot transfer tokens from an arbitrary account. Imagine I have a contract that can transfer tokens from your balance. That does not sound secure, right?

The approach you want to implement is the following: when account `a.testnet` calls a contract, it attaches some tokens with the call (create a transaction with non-zero deposit in `FunctionCall` action), and then, inside the contract, create a `Transfer` to the account `b.testnet`.

In AssemblyScript, you can use `ContractPromiseBatch.create('b.testnet').transfer(context.attachedDeposit)` to issue the transfer.

In Rust, `Promise::new("b.testnet".to_string()).transfer(near_sdk::env::attached_deposit())`

Comment: Note: the funds are always transferred ***from the contract account itself*** *into* the account mentioned in `.create()/new()`

Comment: +1 @Vlad, can you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/70104458/470749 ?   I also just found https://github.com/near/core-contracts/tree/master/lockup which might give me hints (although in Rust).