# NEAR cross-contract calls (allow an account to release funds from escrow to a different account)

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm trying to learn how to allow 1 account (a "donation matcher") to deposit funds into a 2nd account ([this contract](https://github.com/ryancwalsh/donation-matching/blob/0a7bd3e39e79aec480367d0425d807c1915a2310/src/simple/assembly/index.ts#L87-L90), which serves as an "escrow" account), which a 3rd account (a regular "donor") then is allowed to trigger to send to a 4th account (the "recipient", such as a charity).

The function I've written as a placeholder probably doesn't make any sense because I assume that (as currently written) it would probably transfer funds from the caller/signer rather than the escrow/self/contract:

```
function transferFromEscrow(destinationAccount: AccountId, amount: u128): ContractPromiseBatch {
  // TODO: Fix this function!
  const toDestinationAccount = ContractPromiseBatch.create(destinationAccount);
  return toDestinationAccount.transfer(amount);
}
```

Thanks for any help!

This [official NEAR repo](https://github.com/near-examples/cross-contract-calls/tree/a589ab817835f837201f4afa48be5961d8ce5360#organization) led me to expect to see working examples in [index.ts](https://github.com/near-examples/cross-contract-calls/blob/a589ab817835f837201f4afa48be5961d8ce5360/contracts/01.using-single-calls/src/01-local/assembly/index.ts) and [02.using-multiple-calls](https://github.com/near-examples/cross-contract-calls/tree/a589ab817835f837201f4afa48be5961d8ce5360/contracts/02.using-multiple-calls), but I don't see any.

<sub>I also posted this question to https://github.com/near-examples/cross-contract-calls/issues/13</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62677188/how-can-i-move-near-token-from-one-account-to-other-using-contract/62677189), there is no way to withdraw/transfer tokens from some other account, so you should design your contract in such a way that it requires the user to deposit some tokens into your contract (attach tokens with a deposit-like function call). There are nice examples of this pattern in the core contracts:

- [lockup contract](https://github.com/near/core-contracts/tree/master/lockup) locks funds according to the schedule
- [staking-pool](https://github.com/near/core-contracts/tree/master/staking-pool) locks the tokens for delegated stake
- [multisig contract](https://github.com/near/core-contracts/tree/master/multisig) uses two calls to enable 2FA by using `add_request` function with all the parameters of a future call and `confirm` function that takes the previous request and executes it